# Bevy rotation in 2D

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm trying to use Bevy 0.3, and I'm able to use the built-in transforms easily with `Camera2dComponents::default()`.
This is top-down 2D.

The issue is trying to synchronise the player's rotation to the mouse:

```rust
for event in evreader.iter(&cursor_moved_events) {
    println!("{:?}", transform);
    transform.look_at(Vec3::new(event.position.x(), event.position.y(), 0.0), Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    println!("{:?}", transform);
}
```

In this transform is my player's Transform, of course.
Here's what this outputs:

```
Transform { translation: Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation: Quat(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), scale: Vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
Transform { translation: Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation: Quat(0.5012898, -0.49870682, -0.49870682, 0.5012898), scale: Vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) }
```

I'm a bit confused by what `up` is in *look_at* in 2D, but I tried a few different values and the result is always the same: as soon as that look_at runs, the player disappears from view.

Why is the camera not seeing the player anymore after that, and what am I doing wrong with this *look_at*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you're using [`Camera2dComponents`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/prelude/struct.Camera2dComponents.html) which is intended for 2D, [`Transform`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/transform/prelude/struct.Transform.html) is not. `Transform` is more *general*, and includes what's needed for 3D as well.

In your case, it sounds like [`look_at()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/transform/prelude/struct.Transform.html#method.look_at) might not do what you think it does. It creates a [3D look at matrix](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/lookat-function) which computes a view matrix which is "`at`" a position ([`self.translation`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/transform/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.translation)) and looks towards a `target` (the first argument). The `up` is then a 3D vector of what the "world up" is. So that it can calculate the rotation correction.

---

**Updated Solution:**

If you want to rotate the top-down 2D player, i.e. having one side of the player *look* towards the cursor. Then you need to calculate the angle between the position of your player and the target. You can do that easily using [`Vec2::angle_between()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/math/struct.Vec2.html#method.angle_between).

```rust
let pos: Vec2 = ...;
let target: Vec2 = ...;

let angle = (target - pos).angle_between(pos);
transform.rotation = Quat::from_rotation_z(angle);
```

Depending on the orientation of the player itself, i.e. if you're using a sprite, the default orientation could be "looking" to the left or up. Then you might need to offset the `angle`. You can do that by e.g. adding [`+ FRAC_PI_2`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/f32/consts/constant.FRAC_PI_2.html) (or however much is needed.)

Assuming `transform.translation` is the center position of the player, then it will look something like this:

```rust
use bevy::math::{Quat, Vec2};

let pos = transform.translation.truncate();
let target = event.position;

let angle = (target - pos).angle_between(pos);
transform.rotation = Quat::from_rotation_z(angle);
```

---

**Old Answer:**

Since you want to position your camera over the cursor in a top-down 2D view. Then instead you have to use [`from_translation()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/transform/prelude/struct.Transform.html#method.from_translation) or simply shift [`self.translation`](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.3.0/bevy/transform/prelude/struct.Transform.html#structfield.translation), which is the position of your camera.

```rust
transform.translation = Vec3::new(event.position.x(), event.position.y(), 0.0);
```

If you want the cursor position to be at the center of the screen, then you might have to subtract half the screen size.

Comment: Right, that's not what I'm trying to do, I want the player to be "looking at" the mouse, so basically just rotate to always be facing the mouse. I was using look_at with the mouse as a target, hoping that'd change the rotation to be facing the cursor's position, but instead it just makes the player disappear. I am not touching the camera yet, but I'll have it follow the player later on

Comment: @Ulrar Ah I see, I misinterpreted what you wanted. I've updated the answer :)

Comment: if the position is 0,0 or the target and position are the same, this will result in NaN and an error.

Answer (score 10):

For future users I had a similar problem (having a 2d sprite face a mouse click location) in Bevy v0.5 and I could not get the accepted answer to work for whatever reason.

I solved it via this implementation in a Unity thread: https://answers.unity.com/questions/650460/rotating-a-2d-sprite-to-face-a-target-on-a-single.html

Code example:

```
let diff = targ.translation - pos.translation;
let angle = diff.y.atan2(diff.x); // Add/sub FRAC_PI here optionally
pos.rotation = Quat::from_axis_angle(Vec3::new(0., 0., 1.), angle);
```

Comment: Wanted to rewrite top answer with atan because it was not working, saw your and it did worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Posting as accepted solution wasn't completely correct. The idea is that we have positions of player and cursor, but for rotations we need direction vectors:

- Direction of where the player is currently looking
- Direction pointing from player to cursor

Finding angle between these two directions will give us delta to rotate the player by:

```rust
fn rotate_player_to_cursor(
    mut player: Query<&mut Transform, With<Player>>,
    window: Query<&Window, With<PrimaryWindow>>,
    camera: Query<(&Camera, &GlobalTransform), With<MainCamera>>
) {
    // Considering all these tags to have one unique entity each
    let player_transform = player.single();
    let (camera, camera_transform) = camera.single();
    let window = window.single();

    // Extract cursor position if it is inside window
    if let Some(cursor_pos) = window 
        .cursor_position()
        .and_then(|cursor| camera.viewport_to_world_2d(camera_transform, cursor))
    {
        // In 2d up is positive y, so current forward direction for the player
        // is local_y unit vector
        let player_dir = player_transform.local_y().truncate();

        // Direction to cursor (what we want local_y to become) is simply the
        // difference of target position and player position
        let cursor_dir = cursor_pos - player_transform.translation.truncate();
        
        // Then we find the angle between current forward direction and desired one
        let angle = player_dir.angle_between(cursor_dir);
        
        // And finally rotate player along z with that difference
        player_transform.rotate_z(angle);
    }
}
```